# How to implement communication between threads using WinAPI?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to use WinAPI events to communicate between threads. I have one main thread and 2 "worker" threads, which get requests for work and report when done. For simplicity, main thread always sends requests to a specific worker thread; I use dedicated events for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include "process.h"

#define NUM_THREADS 2

struct mywork
{
    int thread_index;
    HANDLE event_do;
    HANDLE event_done;
};

struct mywork gg_work[NUM_THREADS];
uintptr_t gg_threads[NUM_THREADS];

void my_iterate(void* lpParam)
{
    while (1)
    {
        struct mywork* pwork = (struct mywork*)lpParam;
        printf("Worker %d: wait for request\n", pwork->thread_index);
        WaitForMultipleObjects(1, &pwork->event_do, TRUE, INFINITE);
        printf("Worker %d: working\n", pwork->thread_index);

        printf("Worker %d: ready\n", pwork->thread_index);
        SetEvent(pwork->event_done);
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    {
        gg_work[i].thread_index = i;
        gg_work[i].event_do = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("event_do"));
        gg_work[i].event_done = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("event_done"));
        gg_threads[i] = _beginthread(my_iterate, 0, &gg_work[i]);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        for (int thread = 0; thread < NUM_THREADS; ++thread)
        {
            printf("Master: send request to %d\n", thread);
            SetEvent(gg_work[thread].event_do);
        }
        for (int thread = 0; thread < NUM_THREADS; ++thread)
        {
            printf("Master: wait for worker %d\n", thread);
            WaitForMultipleObjects(1, &gg_work[thread].event_done, TRUE, INFINITE);
            printf("Master: got results from worker %d\n", thread);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to run endlessly, but it always gets stuck after sending a few events back and forth. Here is an example output:

```
Master: send request to 0
Master: send request to 1
Master: wait for worker 0
Worker 1: wait for request
Worker 0: wait for request
Worker 1: working
Worker 1: ready
Worker 1: wait for request
Master: got results from worker 0
Master: wait for worker 1
```

Here, the master sets event for worker 0; worker 0 waits for it but never wakes up.

It doesn't always get stuck immediately - sometimes it manages to send a few requests back and forth. But if I use only one worker thread, it runs infinitely (i.e. success).

What am I doing wrong? Should I implement communication between threads using different WinAPI functions? If yes, why?

---

If I replace `SetEvent`/`WaitFor...` by busy-waiting on a boolean flag, protected by a mutex, it works, but is very slow.

---

I use Visual Studio 2017 to compile my code; I link it with the "Multi-threaded Debug DLL" runtime library.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject(gg_work[thread].event_done, INFINITE);` is your error. you need use `WaitForMultipleObjects` in main thread. also possible use `SignalObjectAndWait` in worked threads

Comment: @RbMm: while this might be true, it would be nice to see an explanation of why that sequence deadlocks. Shouldn't `604` be signaling when the worker waits on it, thus un-blocking the worker immediately?

Comment: @YakovGalka - agree - explanation always nice, for understand. i will give it, but need some time to think :)

Comment: and for your debug messages be more easy process - add member to `mywork` - *int i* - index of worked thread - and print "Worker[%u]: wait\n", "Worker[%u]: done\n".. and in main thread print "Master: wait for [%i]", "Master: signal [%i]" - this will be much more informative than multiple events numbers. and almost sure that deadlock by *printf*

Comment: I updated the code to output messages using your idea.

Comment: I tried replacing `WaitForSingleObject` by `WaitForMultipleObjects` and removing all `printf`; didn't help.

Comment: @anatolyg - we can even do better - in every worker thread allocate prefix string with *i* and fill with \t symbols for print from every in self column - this kind of log more easy read. ok - give me some time for test. of course under debugger you can easy  view stack and where thread wait

Comment: *Master: got results from worker 0* but worker 0 not print *working* or *ready* ?

Comment: i run your code, but with *DbgPrint* instead *print* and it not hang (https://pastebin.com/mABAGafn) need more test with *print*

Comment: and `WaitForMultipleObjects` of course you wrong use. it must be not in loop. must be single call for all events. for send request to also must be not loop.

Comment: but i anyway can not catch deadlock, even with your original code - https://pastebin.com/W6r9avJ5 . if you can upload concrete binary file - possible look for it

Comment: @anatolyg: how are you compiling the code? Are you sure you're linking with multi-threaded CRT?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-condition-variables

Comment: it doesn't looks like a normal multithreaded algorithm. you're wasting time for waiting threads job done in a sequence manner. separate events also wasting kernel objects/memory and this is the road to such problems. instead of fixing this wrong one, rewrite it with semaphore for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-semaphore-objects

Answer (score 0):

i can not reproduce deadlock even with original (by sense) code, need debug concrete binary for understand.

```
struct mywork
{
    HANDLE event_do = 0, event_done = 0;
    ULONG i, n;
 
    ~mywork()
    {
        if (event_do) CloseHandle(event_do);
        if (event_done) CloseHandle(event_done);
    }
};
 
ULONG WINAPI WorkThread(PVOID param)
{
    ULONG i = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->i, 
        n = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->n;
 
    HANDLE event_do = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->event_do,
        event_done = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->event_done;
 
    PSTR prefix = (PSTR)alloca(i+1);
    memset(prefix, '\t', i);
    prefix[i] = 0;
 
    do 
    {
        printf("%sWorker[%u]: wait (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
        WaitForSingleObject(event_do, INFINITE);
 
        printf("%sWorker[%u]: .... (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
 
        printf("%sWorker[%u]: done (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
        SetEvent(event_done);
 
    } while (--n);
    
    printf("%sWorker[%u]: exit\n", prefix, i);
 
    return 0;
}
 
void testm()
{
    mywork my[NUM_THREADS], *pmy = my;
    ULONG i = _countof(my), nThreads = 0, n = task_count;
 
    do 
    {
        pmy->i = i;
        pmy->n = n;
        if ((pmy->event_do = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0)) &&
            (pmy->event_done = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0)))
        {
            if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WorkThread, pmy++, 0, 0))
            {
                CloseHandle(hThread);
                nThreads++;
            }
        }
    } while (--i);
 
    if (nThreads)
    {
        do 
        {
            pmy = my, i = nThreads;
            do 
            {
                printf("Master: signal [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, n);
                SetEvent(pmy++->event_do);
            } while (--i);
 
            pmy = my, i = nThreads;
            do 
            {
                printf("Master: wait for [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, n);
                WaitForSingleObject(pmy->event_done, INFINITE);
                printf("Master: result from [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, n);
            } while (pmy++, --i);
 
        } while (--n);
 
        printf("Master: exit\n");
    }
}
```

but anyway this code containing serious logic error - wait separate in loop for every thread. this make dependency between threads (say one thread fast complete self job, but we wait for another thread long time. as result "fast" thread also wait for "slow" thread)

correct solution - wait on all events at once (but must be not more that 64 threads in this case).
so code can be next:

```
struct mywork
{
    HANDLE event_do = 0, event_done = 0;
    ULONG i, n;

    ~mywork()
    {
        if (event_do) CloseHandle(event_do);
        if (event_done) CloseHandle(event_done);
    }
};

ULONG WINAPI WorkThread(PVOID param)
{
    ULONG i = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->i, 
        n = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->n;

    HANDLE event_do = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->event_do,
        event_done = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->event_done;

    PSTR prefix = (PSTR)alloca(i+1);
    memset(prefix, '\t', i);
    prefix[i] = 0;

    for(WaitForSingleObject(event_do, INFINITE);;)
    {
        printf("%sWorker[%u]: .... (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);

        printf("%sWorker[%u]: done (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);

        if (--n)
        {
            printf("%sWorker[%u]: wait (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
            SignalObjectAndWait(event_done, event_do, INFINITE, FALSE);
        }
        else
        {
            SetEvent(event_done);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("%sWorker[%u]: exit\n", prefix, i);

    return 0;
}

void testm()
{
    mywork my[NUM_THREADS], *pmy = my;
    ULONG i = _countof(my), nThreads = 0, n = 8;

    do 
    {
        pmy->i = i;
        pmy->n = n;
        if ((pmy->event_do = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0)) &&
            (pmy->event_done = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0)))
        {
            if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WorkThread, pmy++, 0, 0))
            {
                CloseHandle(hThread);
                nThreads++;
            }
        }
    } while (--i);

    if (nThreads)
    {
        HANDLE Events[_countof(my)], *pEvent = Events;

        pmy = my, i = nThreads;
        do 
        {
            *pEvent++ = pmy->event_done;
            printf("Master: signal [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, n);
            SetEvent(pmy++->event_do);
        } while (--i);

        n = nThreads;

        do 
        {
            i = WaitForMultipleObjects(nThreads, Events, FALSE, INFINITE);

            if (i < nThreads)
            {
                pmy = my + i;

                printf("Master: result from [%u] (%u)\n", i, pmy->n);

                if (--pmy->n)
                {
                    printf("Master: signal [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, pmy->n);
                    SetEvent(pmy->event_do);
                }
                else
                {
                    --n;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                __debugbreak();
            }

        } while (n);

        printf("Master: exit\n");
    }
}
```

but anyway this not good enough solution. not need create `event_done` events. better if every thread have for example `HWHD` handle of main thread which run message loop and `SendMessage` to it window. in this case even `event_do` not need, because `SendMessage` wait internal. possible and post APC to main thread too.

code with APC:

```
struct mywork
{
    HANDLE event_do = 0, hMainThread;
    ULONG i, n, *pnThreads;

    ~mywork()
    {
        if (event_do) CloseHandle(event_do);
    }
};

VOID NTAPI EventDone(_In_ mywork* pmy)
{
    printf("Master: result from [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, pmy->n);

    if (--pmy->n)
    {
        printf("Master: signal [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, pmy->n);
        SetEvent(pmy->event_do);
    }
    else
    {
        --*pmy->pnThreads;
    }
}

ULONG WINAPI WorkThread(PVOID param)
{
    ULONG i = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->i, 
        n = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->n;

    HANDLE event_do = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->event_do,
        hMainThread = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->hMainThread;

    PSTR prefix = (PSTR)alloca(i+1);
    memset(prefix, '\t', i);
    prefix[i] = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("%sWorker[%u]: wait (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
        WaitForSingleObject(event_do, INFINITE);

        printf("%sWorker[%u]: .... (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);

        printf("%sWorker[%u]: done (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
        QueueUserAPC((PAPCFUNC)EventDone, hMainThread, (ULONG_PTR)param);

    } while (--n);
    
    printf("%sWorker[%u]: exit\n", prefix, i);

    return 0;
}

void testm()
{
    mywork my[NUM_THREADS], *pmy = my;
    ULONG i = _countof(my), nThreads = 0, n = task_count;

    if (HANDLE hMainThread = OpenThread(THREAD_SET_CONTEXT, FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId()))
    {
        do 
        {
            pmy->i = i;
            pmy->n = n;
            pmy->hMainThread = hMainThread;
            pmy->pnThreads = &nThreads;

            if (pmy->event_do = CreateEvent(0, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WorkThread, pmy++, 0, 0))
                {
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                    nThreads++;
                }
            }
        } while (--i);

        if (nThreads)
        {
            pmy = my, i = nThreads;
            do 
            {
                printf("Master: signal [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, n);
                SetEvent(pmy++->event_do);
            } while (--i);

            while (STATUS_USER_APC == SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE) && nThreads) continue;
        }
        CloseHandle(hMainThread);
    }

    printf("Master: exit\n");
}
```

code with windows messages:

```
struct mywork
{
    HWND hwnd;
    ULONG i, n;

    enum { WM_DONE = WM_USER };
};

ULONG WINAPI WorkThread(PVOID param)
{
    ULONG i = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->i, 
        n = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->n;

    HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<mywork*>(param)->hwnd;

    PSTR prefix = (PSTR)alloca(i+1);
    memset(prefix, '\t', i);
    prefix[i] = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("%sWorker[%u]: .... (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);

        printf("%sWorker[%u]: done and wait (%u)\n", prefix, i, n);
        SendMessageW(hwnd, mywork::WM_DONE, 0, (LPARAM)param);

    } while (--n);
    
    printf("%sWorker[%u]: exit\n", prefix, i);

    return 0;
}

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    case WM_NCCREATE:
        SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, 
            (LONG_PTR)reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam)->lpCreateParams);
        break;

    case mywork::WM_DONE:
        mywork* pmy = (mywork*)lParam;

        printf("Master: result from [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, pmy->n);

        if (--pmy->n)
        {
            printf("Master: signal [%u] (%u)\n", pmy->i, pmy->n);
        }
        else
        {
            PULONG pnThreads = (PULONG)GetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

            if (!--*pnThreads)
            {
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void testm()
{
    mywork my[NUM_THREADS], *pmy = my;
    ULONG i = _countof(my), nThreads = 0, n = task_count;

    WNDCLASS cls = { 0, WndProc, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, L"my" };

    if (RegisterClassW(&cls))
    {
        if (HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, cls.lpszClassName, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, 0, 0, &nThreads))
        {
            do 
            {
                pmy->i = i;
                pmy->n = n;
                pmy->hwnd = hwnd;

                if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, WorkThread, pmy++, 0, 0))
                {
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                    nThreads++;
                }

            } while (--i);

            if (nThreads)
            {
                MSG msg;

                while (0 < GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
                {
                    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
                }
            }
        }

        UnregisterClassW(cls.lpszClassName, 0);
    }

    printf("Master: exit\n");
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged \[c\], I don't think C has `reinterpret_cast` and destructors.

Comment: @YakovGalka - yes, but this is unrelated to question sense. we can replace `reinterpret_cast<type*>` to `(type*)` cast, can direct use *this* in member functions and direct cal destructor. but sense of question in messaging between thread. *c* or *c++* - no different here